# Can I overclock my AMD A8-6410 APU cpu with ubuntu? If so, how?

Tags: amd-processor, overclocking

Tittle says it all. I am wishing to overclock my cpu, but have looked through BIOS and found nothing. If it helps, it is a HP laptop

Comment: If there's nothing in BIOS then there's likely no way to overclock anything with the current mainboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but overclocking is purely hardware-supported.

Ubuntu won't make a difference in this example, as your motherboard likely does not support clocking the chip to any other mode.

Most laptops don't have this ability, and only certain desktops have the capability for this kind of overclocking.

Maybe you should consider asking on hardware-related sites, since the question here doesn't fit the topics for AskUbuntu.